# Phoenix LiveView dynamic select tags in form troubles

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

In a phoenix LiveView form with 3 select tags, the first influences the other two, i.e. the dependent two should only display the options available for the first one, like so:

```
<%= f = form_for @changeset, "#", id: "eval-form", phx_target: @myself, phx_change: "validate", phx_submit: "save" %>
  <%= select(f, :item1_id, Enum.map(@item1s, fn {_,v} -> {v.name, v.id} end), prompt: "Choose item1...") %>
  <% item1_id = @changeset |> Ecto.Changeset.get_field(:item1_id) %>
  <%= select(f, :item2_id, item1_id && Enum.map(@item1s[item1_id].item2s, &{&1.name, &1.id}) || []) %>
  <%= select(f, :item3_id, item1_id && Enum.map(@item1s[item1_id].item3s, &{&1.name, &1.id}) || []) %>
</form>
```

When `item1` gets chosen, `item2` and `item3` select tags do include the correct respective options, but display no chosen item (as they do not include a prompt, the first option should be selected). The changeset does not include changes for `item2` and `item3` (which matches what is displayed). However, after `item2` is chosen, `item3` displays the first option as chosen (as intended). After that, the changeset does include `item1` and `item2` changes, but `item3` selected option is not there.

Questions:

1. How to get the dependent select tags (`item2` and `item3`) to show their respective first option as chosen after a change to the first select (`item1`)?
2. How to get the 'default' options from the dependent select tags into the changeset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with 'two phase changeset casting'.

When handling `phx-change` event, firstly the `item1` attribute is cast and validated. Next, `item2` and `item3` attributes are changed if needed (i.e. item values and selected value). Finally, `item2` and `item3` attributes are cast and validated.

It seems that this also works for any dynamic forms (e.g. in my case when `item1` is selected, items for `item2` are set, when `item2` is selected additional fields appear that are needed for the `item2`).

I'm open to suggestions if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `value` option for `select` tags? Like this:

```
<%= item2_values = item1_id && Enum.map(@item1s[item1_id].item2s, &{&1.name, &1.id}) || [] %>
<%= select(f, :item2_id, item2_values, value: @changeset |> Ecto.Changeset.get_field(:item2_id, List.first(item2_values))) %>
```

However, I think you should do this logic in your LiveView module. If you have a `phx-change` event being fired from your form, you could actually assign `item2_values` to the socket in a clean function.

Comment: This only works 'visually': the value is shown in `select`, but not included in the changeset. Doing the logic in LiveView module seems the way to go, as per [LiveEEx pitfalls in the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/assigns-eex.html#liveeex-pitfalls). It does not change the functioning, however.